# Switch unity event system target

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I would like to replace the target of unity's event system with one that i manually designate elsewhere via code.

This is to allow regular unity events to trigger appropriately for a nearby object even though the pointer may not be directly on the target. (Aim assist / pointer snapping/stabilization)

My problem is that even though i update the event system's selected game object with the desired target, the unity event system doesn't trigger as it still believes that the pointer isn't over a target. (Although the in editor event system debug dialog, and Highlight effects (for UI elements) trigger accordingly and shows that the selected target has changed.)

```
//Raycast to snapped object
Physics.Raycast(pos, rot, out hitInfo, 20f);
//Populate pointer event data using current
PointerEventData ped = new PointerEventData(EventSystem.current);

//Update data using snapped objects data
ped.pointerCurrentRaycast = new RaycastResult {
   distance = hitInfo.distance,
   gameObject = focusedObject,
   sortingLayer = hitInfo.transform.gameObject.layer,
   worldNormal = hitInfo.normal,
   worldPosition = hitInfo.point
};

//Update current target - Target changes in unity debug dialog, but has no effect on clickability
EventSystem.current.SetSelectedGameObject(focusedObject, ped);
```

What am i missing?

**-- Edit For Clarification --**

I currently use ray-casting and distance based code to snap the pointer to the target on non-GUI components enabling target snapping pointer based selection. Once the non-GUI target is "snapped" i utilize ExecuteEvents.ExecuteHierarchy for IPointerEnter/Exit/Down/Up/Click to manually triggering events as needed.

For GUI component targets though, if i leverage the same custom event code i loose the ability to interact with more complex, dynamic GUI components without multiple workarounds and adding colliders to each GUI element. I'd like to avoid having to re-engineer unity's input module to support pointer snapping as the default input module works quite well out of the box on GUI components once the pointer enters their bounds.

**-- Edit 2 --**

I should add that i'm using Unity's HoloLensInputModule, and HoloLensInput to handle UI interactions, while using my own raycasts to handle non-ui components.

It appears as though i'll need to extend HoloLensInput.cs's `GetGazeScreenPosition()` with my snapping code in order to no longer need to be concerned with updating the event system

**-- Mostly Resolved --**

I've mostly resolved the issue, by extending StandaloneInputModule, and BaseInput and overriding multiple methods throughout their inheritance structure. (It's ugly but works, and is running more efficiently as i'm able to drop unwanted extra RaycastAll calls)

The crux of the matter is to override not only the RaycastAll call buried deep within the inherited classes, but also any time the eventData is requested, or manipulated. The bulk of the changes relate to `GetMousePointerEventData()`, and `ProcessMouseEvent()` and almost all method calls chained within including children recursively.

That being said, there is an issue with scrollbars, which jump between min and max scroll. The issue appears to be coming from the pointerEventData.position value that's used internally by the slider after `ProcessDrag()'s ExecuteEvents.Execute(pointerEvent.pointerDrag, pointerEvent, ExecuteEvents.dragHandler);`

Comment: So you're asking how to for instance distinguish between whether you are snapping to a slider's thumb or just part of the dragging area? I don't think Unity can do much for you, you'd have to use Graphics Raycasts and if a slider is the closest thing, you look at its state and calculate what position of it you're closest to. Maybe then you can execute an event on it at that position.

Comment: The snapping code for the pointer's visual update is working. It's after the pointer snaps, unity's Standalone Input Module's ray-cast technically remains pointed straight forward from the camera. This leaves the pointer visuals and the Input Module targets out of alignment until the snap is released. The pointer says i'm on the target, which highlights as i call SetSelectedObject, but the Input Module's Down/Click/Up events ignore the SetSelectedObject in favor of their internal ray-cast result.

The more i dig the more it looks as though i'm going to have to extend unitys class.

Answer (score 0):

The first issue is that `SetSelectedGameObject` does not send or forward an event to a game object. It's for the purposes of changing what the event system is tracking as the selected game object and can send `OnSelect` and `OnDeselect` events.

If you want to actually execute an event with a particular target, you'll need to use [`ExecuteEvents.Execute`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EventSystems.ExecuteEvents.Execute.html) which takes a `GameObject` to be the target of the event.

Also, It's not enough to only modify incoming pointer events. No event occurs when a mouse is moved over nothing, but you would need to check if a nearby object needs to receive an `OnMouseEnter` event anyway!

You'll need to have code that runs every frame and is capable of creating and/or modifying `PointerEventData` and then executing the appropriate event with [`ExecuteEvents`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EventSystems.ExecuteEvents.html)

I don't know if there is a way to intercept and discard events before the gameobject receives them, but you'll want to be mindful of your system and the build in one executing redundant events. For example, your system will execute `OnMouseEnter` `OnMouseStay` potentially long before the built-in one does, and the target `GameObject` being called may need code to ignore the built-in executions of these events.

Depending on your situation, it is probably easier to simply use the built-in events and use a larger colliders that are meant for only receiving mouse events.

One way to do this is setting `Physics.queriesHitTriggers = true;`, adding a child GameObjectwith a "thicker" version of the collider (exactly what that means may depend on the original collider), and setting it to be a trigger so that it doesn't interfere with physics. Then, you implement `OnMouseEnter` etc. in a script on that child GameObject instead of the original one.

Comment: I may have poorly communicated the crux of my issue, added more information/clarification to my post.

Comment: I've added more information and updated the post after extending the standalone input module.

Comment: @Reahreic That's good info! It could certainly be an [answer to this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)